# Post Array of values from View back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to pass all data from an array inside my view back to a controller.  I'm not sure how to do this using my ViewModel.

Model Class

```
public class ResultsViewModel
{
    public int?[] ProgramIds { get; set; }

}
```

Form inside of the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportCsv", "SurveyResponse", FormMethod.Post))

{

   // Should I be looping through all values in the array here?
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProgramIds)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Controller I am posting to

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportCsv(ResultsViewModel ResultsViewModel)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should I be looping through all values in the array here?

Yes, but don't use @Html.HiddenFor(..), since it seems to generate invalid HTML, because it generates controls with identical IDs:

```
<input id="ProgramIds" name="ProgramIds" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input id="ProgramIds" name="ProgramIds" type="hidden" value="4" />
```

Instead loop the list and create your own hidden html fields:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProgramIds.Length; i++) 
{ 
    <input type="hidden" name="ProgramIds[@i]" value="@Model.ProgramIds[i]" />
}
```

Scott Hanselman has written a blog post about this:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`Should I be looping through all values in the array here?`

Yes, try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProgramIds.Length; i++) 
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ProgramIds[i]) 
}
```